# PHP populated FullCalendar, looks right, but data wont show

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using mySQL to store information about check-out dates, and then depending on the object I would like to display the times that are already taken with FullCalendar.js

I am using PHP to pull in rows and then loop through them populating the  where events are created, the code looks right when I check it on the page, but data is not loaded.

Here is the code generating the page:

```
function getAllTimes(){
    if(!empty($_GET['id']))
    {
        $query = "
            SELECT userID, startDate, endDate
            FROM checkout
            Where equID =" .$_GET['id'];          


        global $db;
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $(document).ready(function() {    

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: [";
        $counter = 0;

       foreach($rows as $row):
         if($counter == 0)
         {
           echo "
                    {   
                        title  : '".$row['userID']."',
                        start  : '".$row['startDate']."',
                        end    : '".$row['endDate']."'
                    }";
                    $counter = $counter+1; 
         } 
        else
        {
            echo ",
                    {   
                        title  : '".$row['userID'].",'
                        start  : '".$row['startDate'].",'
                        end    : '".$row['endDate']."'
                    }";
                    $counter = $counter+1; 
        }
        endforeach;            
         echo   "
         ]
     });
}}";
        echo "
        </script>";

    }
    else
        echo "ID must be specified";

}

getAllTimes();
```

And this is the outcome when loaded, yet events are not added to the calendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {    

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: [
                    {   
                        title  : 'ArtemBeer',
                        start  : '2014-01-16 00:00:00',
                        end    : '2014-01-16 00:00:00'
                    },
                    {   
                        title  : 'ArtemBeer,'
                        start  : '2014-01-15 00:00:00,'
                        end    : '2014-01-16 00:00:00'
                    },
                    {   
                        title  : 'ArtemBeer,'
                        start  : '2014-01-09 02:02:00,'
                        end    : '2014-01-10 03:03:00'
                    }
         ]
     });
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data (JS) has a bad comma:

```
start  : '2014-01-15 00:00:00,'
```

should be:

```
start  : '2014-01-15 00:00:00',
```

Also use your **Chrome Inspector** to see JS errors via the console, otherwise you will be guessing all day long.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted the comma, but it didn't fix it, although when I directly inserted my html output into java.js that technically just initialize the calendar, the data displays, yet it won't initialize it from php

Comment: Thanks, it was the closing tag, apparently I never closed the function